# Vue Cant load component files

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I've recently started getting this error on webpack build.

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors

These relative modules were not found:

* ./components/component1.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js
* ./components/component2.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js
* ./components/component3.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js
```

### app.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    const Vue = require('vue');

    // Register all our parent components
    Vue.component('component1', require('./components/component1.vue'));
    Vue.component('component2', require('./components/component2.vue'));
    Vue.component('component3', require('./components/component3.vue'));

    // Initialise the root vue instance.
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
});
```

### What I've done so far:

- This used to work and I've checked out older branches and ran `npm
  install` again.
- I've tried listing the absolute path in the require statements and if I do that I get this error instead:

---

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors 12:14:37 PM
These dependencies were not found:

 /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/hourly-wage.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js
 /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/search.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js
 /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/hiring-demand.vue in ./resources/assets/js/lmi/app.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/hourly-wage.vue /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/search.vue /resources/assets/js/lmi/components/hiring-demand.vue
```

---

I'm not sure what is going on. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If it was working on previous build, check directory structure (Always work!)

Comment: @hamzox I reverted back to an old commit to check this and it's no longer working. I ran npm install again and nothing. I'll tinker a bit more as it's bound to be a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: Did you update node recently? Sometimes it causes regressions.

Comment: @LuisOrduz Not that I know of. I updated it anyway and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. This was an NPM problem. I got a work colleagues to run the same command on his machine and it worked. So to narrow it down I quickly installed yarn to see if it would work and it did...

npm 5.4.2 is the version I had issues with.